# What do I do with the gap under the window?

Tags: windows, window-frame

Just installed new vinyl windows from the inside. The outside lip slopes downward and it’s a gap about 1/2" - 1".
What can I do to fill it in and make it look nice or cover?
Want to prevent water and bugs from getting under there.

[image]

https://imgur.com/a/hxt0yAH

Comment: Simplest might be to surround the window with trim to hide that gap. The bottom trim, as noted, needs to be able to weep/drain any water that gets in.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad it could not have been set tighter to the sill for looks. I typically do not caulk that part of the window to the sill. The sill, with its' slope will drain away any surface water that lands on it. Over time if any of the perimeter caulk should fail, which it normally does, and lets water in at the sides, if the bottom was caulked, it will hold the water in like a dam and allow the water to rise above the slope to let the water run back into the framing.

To fix the issue, since it is a vinyl window and setting wood trim would invite rot in a fast hurry, use PVC trim available in the big box stores. Rip it to fit  in the space and recess it a bit. Keep it in place by bonding it to the underside of the bottom of the window. Use an adhesive caulk to do so.

Test the piece for fit first, then apply a thin layer on both, the piece and the window, by running a bead then tooling it flat with a putty knife or flat stick. Do the same on the underside of the window projection, though you may need to apply it with the stick since the caulk gun may not allow you to place it properly.

Set the piece back in the space and hold it to the underside of the window by using 3 or 4 small shims to force it up to the underside of the window, just snugging it into place.